# Puppeteer does not load the page fully but it counts as loaded

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

So basically my puppeteer goes to the page but its does not render/load fully but acts as it did. [image]

[image]

What may seem to cause this problem, because I cant figure out since it does not give my any error but the code does not work as it should because later on, when I join the stocks table part of the app, it does not even load my tables but puppeteer acts as it did.

This is how the other pages looks the it is supposed to be "loaded", there should be a list of tables but all I get is nothing and also my chromium freezes.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to scroll down to get all contents.

This code works that web site

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getTitles() {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        await page.goto('https://www.stockrover.com/#:~:text=Stock%20Rover%20is%20the%20AAII,site%20provides%20for%20its%20users.&text=Stock%20Rover%20provides%20tons%20of,it%20easy%20to%20research%20investments.');

        // scroll down end of page
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            window.scrollTo(0, window.document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
        // extract the titles from web page
        const titles = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h3.spot__heading'));
            return links.map(a => ({
                title: a.innerText,
            }));
        });
        await browser.close();
        return Promise.resolve(titles);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

getTitles()
    .then((titles) => console.log(titles))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

```
$ node get-data.js
[
  { title: "Rover's Weekly Market Brief - 12/23/2022" },
  { title: 'Keeping Track of your Portfolios in Stock Rover' },
  { title: 'Earnings Reports in Stock Rover' },
  { title: 'Finding Your Perfect ETFs In Stock Rover' },
  { title: '3 Dividend Screeners' },
  { title: 'Screening by Relative Strength' },
  { title: 'More Features Added to Stock Rover V8' },
  { title: 'Real World Screener Performance' },
  { title: 'Quick and Dirty Way to Test if a Stock is Undervalued' },
  { title: 'New Features Added to Stock Rover V8' }
]
```

[image]

Comment: This may be helpful, but the question is tagged Puppeteer-Sharp, so it's not clear what OP's using. We should probably wait for a [mcve] before answering...